# SVG image is not shown immediately on mobile screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the  below `SVG` image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <XamSvg.SvgImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            local:svg="res:images.Q317664"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawableAutoSize"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="#AAD39F" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to display this `SVG` but when I run this code the `SVG` image not displayed on my mobile screen. when I touch on mobile screen 15 t0 20 times then it displays as expected. How can I fix this?
Why is image getting late on mobile screen?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using XamSvg;
using Android.Graphics;
namespace App18
{
[Activity(Label = "App18", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int[] rawIds;
    int[] drawableViewIds;
    private string[] sharedNames;

    int currentId;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
         Setup.InitSvgLib();

        //Tells XamSvg in which assembly to search for svg when "res:" is used
         var assembly = typeof(MainActivity).Assembly;

        XamSvg.Shared.Config.ResourceAssembly = assembly;





        //Get all svg resource ids in the drawable folder
        rawIds = typeof(Resource.Drawable)
            .GetFields()
            .Where(f => f.IsLiteral)
            .Select(f => (int)f.GetRawConstantValue())
            .ToArray();

        //Get all drawing zones in the current layout
       drawableViewIds = typeof(Resource.Id)
            .GetFields()
            .Where(f => f.IsLiteral && f.Name.StartsWith("drawable"))
            .Select(f => (int)f.GetRawConstantValue())
           .ToArray();

        //Get all svg resources in the shared assembly
        sharedNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(n => n.EndsWith(".svg")).OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();

        //When clicked, change the svg source in all zones
        var contentView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.content);
        contentView.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(currentId<rawIds.Length)
                LoadImageTest(rawIds[currentId]);
            else
         {
       }

        };
        LoadImageTest(rawIds[currentId++]);

    }

    void LoadImageTest(int rawId)
    {
        foreach (var drawableId in drawableViewIds)
        {

            var v = FindViewById<ImageView>(drawableId);
           var drawable = SvgFactory.GetDrawable(Resources, rawId);
         v.SetImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Xamarin.Forms` code for `XamSvg` library. Try `Xamarin.Android` code instead, as your project is targeting `Android` devices. Here is the code from the [XamSvg component store Getting Started guide](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamsvg):

> Android 3.1+ (api 12)
>
> Open your Android project, open nuget, then add "XamSvg". The nuget package has been copied in your local cache by the component installer.
>
> Add a folder called raw under the standard resources folder
>
> Add your svg images to this raw folder. Make sure they have the AndroidResource build action.
>
> In your Application or MainActivity class, initialize the Svg lib by calling XamSvg.Setup.InitSvgLib(); This is very quick and binds the cross platform color helper with the specific android version.

```
[Application]
public class MainApp : Application
{
    public MainApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        XamSvg.Setup.InitSvgLib();
    }
}
```

> To display myimage.svg image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
        <XamSvg.SvgImageView
            local:svg="@raw/myimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, but he is using Xamarin.Forms version, which requires local:svg="res:images.Q317664" to set the image, while Xamarin.Android requires to set it as local:svg="@raw/myimage"

Comment: Error 1 No resource found that matches the given name (at 'svg' with value '@raw/Q317664').

Comment: See my updated answer. It includes the steps required to include the image in your project and then reference it in the SvgImageView. NOTE: The first step I suppose you've already done it, as I think the nuget package is already included in the project.

Comment: @LuisBeltran hey i have similar problem but mine is not error except it does not show my SVG files. do i need to add this in my app      [Application]
public class MainApp : Application
{
    public MainApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        XamSvg.Setup.InitSvgLib();
    }
}